# What does ctrl+arrow do in vim within tmux, and how do I skip words?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, vim, tmux, ubuntu-20.04

I am used to using vim in a normal gnome-terminal, in which by default `ctrl`+`arrow` can skip words. However, if I am using vim in tmux, these key combinations would delete lines of words.

Question:

- What does `ctrl`+`arrow` do when using vim in tmux?
- How can I skip words in this case?

More information:

- OS: ubuntu20.04
- gnome-terminal version: 3.36.2
- tmux version: 3.0a
- vim version: 8.1

Comment: the key to skip words in vim is `w`, not Ctrl+Arrow like in GUI. Probably you need to run `vimtutor` to learn more about how to use vim

Comment: @phuclv But in a usual GUI, ctrl+arrow does skip words (even in vim), which is what I am used to. Are you saying this is caused by tmux rather than vim? In this case how can I configure it to skip words with ctrl+arrow?

Comment: I never use tmux so I don't know. You need to check the tmux key mapping in your PC